# Opencart product.tpl

Tags: opencart

Where did I miss to add a line of code if I try to echo php variable inside OPENCART product.tpl file and it doesn't show up on site?

Notes: there is a field in database. I am able to save to this field from admin panel ( i added a custom field there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did You edit also the product controller to load the variable and pass it to the template? I guess not... Edit `catalog/controller/product/product.php` and add `$this->data['MYVARIABLE'] = $product_info['MYVARIABLE'];` somewhere before `$this->render()` is called.